# Server POST request from mongo script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cron

I develop a chess playing website, and want some games to be automatically started under some conditions. So I'm writing a (cron) mongo script to

1. Create the games
2. Send a (POST?) message to the server saying "these games have started"

(The server then would notify connected users using socket.io).

---

I've done 1., but have no idea how to do 2. (or even if it's possible).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think the answer is no, and I can live without. But it would be nice if there was a way to send basic http requests from mongo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of someone faces the same problem, I solved it using the module "node-cron" (available on npmjs.com), thus getting rid of mongo scripts.